# correct sentence with or without usage of "which"

Tags: which-that

In my technical report, I am bit confused that which of the following two sentences is correct or proper.

> An important challenge remains to be addressed in the IoT is the ease of application development for the stakeholders **involved in the application development**.

OR

> An important challenge remains to be addressed in the IoT is the ease of application development for the stakeholders, **which are involved in the application development**.

Comment: First, the *which* should be *who* (unless the stakeholders aren't people). Second, the two sentences are both grammatical, but mean two different things; do you want a restrictive or a non-restrictive clause? Third, you have two verbs in the sentence (*remains* and *is*). You need to get rid of one of them, or put one of them in a dependent clause.

Comment: Thanks Peter for suggestion. I want to use non-restrictive clause.

Comment: @Pankesh Patel: Like some of your previous questions, this is essentially proofreading. But I'm calling it Too Localised, because  the specific contexts you ask about are unlikely to be relevant to future visitors. In this particular case, your first version is correct except you're missing the word *"that"* (and I would discard one *"the"*, the odd usage of *"stakeholders"*, and repetition of *"application development"*). It would be better phrased as *An important challenge **that** remains to be addressed in the IoT **is ease** of application development for **those working on this task.***

Comment: Please let us know if you have checked out ELL at http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners?referrer=Flyp9GdUZG08GxFV_g6lKw2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The stakeholders involved" and "the stakeholders who [not which] are involved" mean the same thing, and it's a matter of taste which you use. Both imply that some, but not necessarily all, of the stakeholders are involved. "The stakeholders, who are involved" means that you're talking about the stakeholders and then saying that they're involved. That is, all the stakeholders are involved.

Side issue: You need to say "An important challenge *which* remains to be addressed."

Comment: Thanks gmcgath for answer and your  correction. Can I write above mentioned statement  in the following way :  _An important challenge, which remains to be addressed in the IoT is the ease of application development for the involved stakeholders_.

Comment: Almost. You need a comma after "the IoT".